# How can i see the get methods parameters and definition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

New to rails : Learning how to create APIs in Rails using http://apionrails.icalialabs.com/book/chapter_three , There is this below excerpt that simulates a "get" request, but i want to know how I can look at what the parameters of the method are , and which class is it present in. At this point it looks like magic and i dont know if its a rspec / ruby / rails or a gem, and I am getting tired searching through documentations and i would really like to find it out via code (some run time way perhaps).

```rb
require 'spec_helper'

  describe Api::V1::UsersController do
    before(:each) do
      request.headers['Accept'] = "application/vnd.marketplace.v1"
    end

    describe "GET #show" do
      before(:each) do
        @user = FactoryBot.create :user
        get :show, params: { id: @user.id }, format: :json
      end

       it "returns the information about a reporter on a hash" do
        user_response = JSON.parse(response.body, symbolize_names: true)
        expect(user_response[:email]).to eql @user.email
      end

      it { should respond_with 200 }
    end
  end
```

Comment: Basically you want to debug what parameters are you getting. For that, you can write `byebug` in your code. It is ruby gem for debugging which is by default installed in rails. you can check more about byebug here `https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug` . Please check the commands for more understanding

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know `rspec / ruby / rails` then it will be very difficult to understand it but let me try.

```
describe Api::V1::UsersController
```

This tells that the spec is written for `Api::V1::UsersController` which you will find it in `app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb`

```
get :show, params: { id: @user.id }, format: :json
```

This line tells that call `show` action of above controller with parameter `{ id: @user.id }` and the request type `json`

If you want to check parameters received in `show` action of above controller you can use `byebug` utility to inspect `params`, `request`, `controller_name`, `action_name` etc

Check https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug for how to use byebug to debug the application.

Comment: How do i know what are the parameters to the get method ? I can always get parameters to show action by simply going to the code base , but what I would like to know is where is the code that documents the parameters to the get simulator method.

Comment: Check https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs/controller-spec